# How can we make Tab layout auto hide?

Tags: java, android

generally we can hide particular tabs at runtime. but I need to make make whole tab layout hideable. when I click the screen once it appears and other time it will disappear. Can this possible. I have seen this in motorola Droid X phone's camera application.
please Help me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `setVisibility(8);` :)

you put an Id in your linearLayout and manage it in the code  with:

```
LinearLayout l=(LynearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myId);
l.setOnClickListener(this);

public void OnClick(View v){
    myTab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Do not hard-code magic values like `8`. Use the appropriate constants, like `View.GONE`.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses a TabActivity. The key point is to make its TabWidget invisible.

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        TabHost host = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        spec = host.newTabSpec("one")
            .setIndicator(getText(R.string.oneTabIndicator),
                    resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_one))
            .setContent(new Intent().setClass(this, OneActivity.class));
        host.addTab(spec);
        OneActivity child = (OneActivity)getLocalActivityManager().getActivity("one");
        child.registerParentActivity(this);
            // and so on for other tabs
    }

    public void toggleTabs() {
        TabWidget tab = getTabHost().getTabWidget();
        int visibility = View.GONE;
        if (tab.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            visibility = View.VISIBLE;
        }
        tab.setVisibility(visibility);
    }

}
```

And...

```
public class OneActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doToggle();
            }
        });
    }

    private void doToggle() {
        ((MainActivity)myParentActivity).toggleTabs();
    }

    public void registerParentActivity(Activity parent) {
        myParentActivity = parent;
    }
}
```

You just need to decide on the mechanism that you want to use to call your version of toggleTabs().